# How do I enable SecuredSettingsEnabled when using AxMsRdpClient to connect through RDP to a Cloud Instance?

Tags: c#, .net, rdp

I've searched the web high and low and just cannot wrap my head around this.

Basically I want to connect to a windows server 2008 instance, located in the cloud and run a batch file (which is located on the instance).

I'm using the AxMSTSCLib and MSTSCLib to connect to it through RDP, but cannot get the batch running. The problem is SecuredSettingsEnabled isn't enabled so I am restricted doing this kind of operation.

How do I connect properly, so that SecuredSettingsEnabled is set to True and I can run my batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can cast the AdvancedSettings property of the AxMsTsc client to your desired settings interface. Then you can access all settings, which are available. Got through this to enable SmartSizing for my tabbed RDP Session Tool in WPF.</strike>

```
this.Client = new AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting();
IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings7 settings = 
    (IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings7)this.Client.AdvancedSettings;
settings.SmartSizing = true;
```

The answer is answering an entirely different question. I misread the original question. See my last comment for details and a hint I found in the documentation. Sorry for any inconvenience!

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question?

Comment: The problem was, that the property he desired to set is not available in the default interface. If you cast to the client properties to specific interfaces like `IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings7` additional properties will be available, which were added later to the ActiveX Component.

Comment: still I got (-1) for SecuredSettingsEnabled, can you please show me the code to enable it

Comment: Just realized that my answer ist not answering the question, too. I misread it and thought it was the typical request for additional properties *shame*. According to the documentation the property SecuredSettingsEnabled is read-only and indicates, if the client is currently in a the Internet Explorer URL security zones. So I assume that it is required to get the client into trust zone, in order to be able to set the secured settings properly (e.g. start the batch file via StartProgram). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382894(v=vs.85).aspx