# SecuredSettingsEnabled always returning false (-1) - Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: c#

I'm developing a win app that provides a remote desktop connection to a
terminal server. I'm testing it by using my windows xp pro system as the
server. I can connect to it just fine. it's working quite nicely. but I'm
required to also launch a particular app when the user logs in. I found
instructions on how to do that, but I can't seem to make it work. whenever
i check the `SecuredSettingsEnabled` property, I always get `-1` returned. and,
of course, I've also tried calling `SecuredSettings.StartProgram` to launch
the app, but that won't work either.

How do I enable secured settings so that the StartProgram call works?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried anything from this answer?

[How do I enable SecuredSettingsEnabled when using AxMsRdpClient to connect through RDP to a Cloud Instance?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634217/how-do-i-enable-securedsettingsenabled-when-using-axmsrdpclient-to-connect-throu

Comment: i use this code but dont work

Comment: in fact ,i not found  SecuredSettingsEnabled property in this interface!!!!

Comment: how can log of from win  with this class ?